# UsingRosEd beginner tutorial defaults to Spanish?

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-kinetic, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

It appears that the beginner tutorial for ROS Editors found at the following link has been changed to Spanish.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRosEd

Where can I find an English version of this tutorial?

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350120/usingrosed-beginner-tutorial-defaults-to-spanish?/) by [David M](https://answers.ros.org/users/53812/david-m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
I think it's not Spanish, but Portuegese.

It's likely related to these [ROS Discourse posts](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-brasil-meet-up/13698/9).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
I've posted a comment on that thread: [link](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-brasil-meet-up/13698/38).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's been restored: [Discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-brasil-meet-up/13698/39), ROS wiki [diff](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRosEd?action=diff&rev2=40&rev1=39).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1